# Segal-Freed-Hopkins-Teleman = Atiyah-Hirzebruch/Leray-Serre?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, stacks

[Freed-Hopkins-Teleman](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1906) (section 3.7) generalise [Segal's](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1968__34__129_0) (Proposition 5.3) spectral sequence for equivariant K-theory to more general *local* quotient groupoids (that is, topological groupoids locally weakly equivalent to the action of a compact Lie group on a Hausdorff space, eg a proper Lie groupoid). For this question I am only interested in the *untwisted* K-theory, and ultimately only in proper Lie groupoids, where the Hausdorff space in the definition can be taken as an open ball in a representation.

The definition of the $E_2$ page for the groupoid $X= (X_1\rightrightarrows X_0)$ is
$$
E_2^{p,q} = H^p(X_0/X_1,\mathcal{K}^q)
$$ 
where $\pi\colon X_0\to X_0/X_1$ is the (proper!) quotient map to the orbit space and $\mathcal{K}^q$ is the sheafification of the direct image presheaf $\pi_\ast K^q(-)$, for $K^q(-)$ the presheaf $U\mapsto K^q(U)$. This converges to $K^{p+q}(X)$, which in the case of an action groupoid (Segal's original version) is just equivariant K-theory.

If I define an equivalence relation $R$ on $X_0$  (or rather the corresponding groupoid) to be the image of $(s,t)\colon X_1 \to X_0\times X_0$, then $R \to X_0/X_1$ is a weak (or local) equivalence, and one can consider the sheaf $\mathcal{K}^q$ as living on $R$. Then $X\to R$ can be seen as a kind of stratified gerbe, for the family of groups on $X_0$ with fibre over $x\in X_0$ the automorphism group $G_x$ of $x$. The stalk of $\mathcal{K}^q$ at $x$ is $K^q(\ast//G_x)$. Now this seems to me to be a version of Atiyah-Hirzebruch/Leray-Serre for a gerbe instead of a fibration or bundle in spaces. My question is

> Has anyone made this analogy more precise? That is, written down generalities for spectral sequences of AH-type in topological stacks?